# The bidual of a Banach space

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, weak-topology

Let $E$ a Banach space, and and we define on $E^*$ its topological dual, with the weak* topology.

I read in my text book that $$(E^*,\sigma(E^*,E))^*=E$$
If $E$ is locally convex.
And I wanted to make sure if the duality depends in the first place of the topology we define on the space ?

Comment: Dual space is the space of all continuous linear functionals. Being continuous depends on the the topology.